# Github Actions - Strange issue with building Layers

Tags: aws-lambda, github-actions, serverless-framework

I can deploy locally no problem but it fails on Github actions with this message:

```
15s
Run serverless/github-action@v3.2
/usr/bin/docker run --name bedb4010df24ad667491aa53d7f8e25a3e8ef_827437 --label 5bedb4 --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e "JAVA_HOME" -e "JAVA_HOME_11_X64" -e "GRADLE_BUILD_ACTION_SETUP_COMPLETED" -e "GRADLE_BUILD_ACTION_CACHE_RESTORED" -e "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" -e "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" -e "INPUT_ARGS" -e "INPUT_ENTRYPOINT" -e "HOME" -e "GITHUB_JOB" -e "GITHUB_REF" -e "GITHUB_SHA" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER" -e "GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_ID" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR_ID" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_TRIGGERING_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW" -e "GITHUB_HEAD_REF" -e "GITHUB_BASE_REF" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_NAME" -e "GITHUB_SERVER_URL" -e "GITHUB_API_URL" -e "GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL" -e "GITHUB_REF_NAME" -e "GITHUB_REF_PROTECTED" -e "GITHUB_REF_TYPE" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_REF" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_SHA" -e "GITHUB_WORKSPACE" -e "GITHUB_ACTION" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REF" -e "GITHUB_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ENV" -e "GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY" -e "GITHUB_STATE" -e "GITHUB_OUTPUT" -e "RUNNER_OS" -e "RUNNER_ARCH" -e "RUNNER_NAME" -e "RUNNER_ENVIRONMENT" -e "RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE" -e "RUNNER_TEMP" -e "RUNNER_WORKSPACE" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN" -e "ACTIONS_CACHE_URL" -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true --entrypoint "/bin/sh" -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/siam-rewards/siam-rewards":"/github/workspace" 5bedb4:010df24ad667491aa53d7f8e25a3e8ef -c "serverless plugin install --name serverless-iam-roles-per-function && serverless deploy --stage dev"
Running "serverless" from node_modules

✔ Plugin "serverless-iam-roles-per-function" installed  (2s)
Running "serverless" from node_modules

Deploying app-rewards to stage dev (eu-west-1)
Creating deployment bucket 'deployment-bucket-app-rewards'...
Updated deployment bucket public access block


[ LayersPlugin ]: => samplelib
... ○ Downloading __meta__/manifest-settings.json from bucket...
... ⊗ =============================================================
... ⊗ NOTE: You're currently using incompatible version [v18.17.0]
... ⊗ =============================================================

... ○ __meta__/manifest-settings.json The specified key does not exist..
... ○ Uploading remote __meta__/manifest-settings.json...
... ○ OK...

× Stack app-rewards-dev failed to deploy (4s)
Environment: linux, node 18.17.0, framework 3.33.0 (local) 3.34.0v (global), plugin 6.2.3, SDK 4.3.2
Credentials: Local, environment variables
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'src/layer/nodejs/node_modules/samplelib'

1 deprecation found: run 'serverless doctor' for more details
```

Here is my serverless.yml

```
#comment
service: app-rewards
frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: eu-west-1

  deploymentBucket:
    name: deployment-bucket-app-rewards
    serverSideEncryption: AES256
    blockPublicAccess : true

  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - s3:PutObject
      Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::deployment-bucket-app-rewards/*"
      
  

plugins:
   - serverless-appsync-plugin   # doc https://github.com/sid88in/serverless-appsync-plugin/tree/master/doc
   - serverless-iam-roles-per-function
   - serverless-plugin-log-retention
   - serverless-layers
   - serverless-jetpack
   - serverless-deployment-bucket

custom:
  logRetentionInDays: 1  
  testName : foobarx
  serverless-layers:
    - samplelib:
        functions: 
          - getSampleMessage
        dependenciesPath: ./package.json
        localDir:
          name: samplelib
          path: ./src/layer/nodejs/node_modules/samplelib
          folders:
            include:
              - '*.js'
            exclude:
              - node_modules
        

  # jetpack:
  #   trace: true
  #   preInclude:
  #     # STEP 1: Start with nothing.
  #     - "!**"

# package:
#   individually: true
#   exclude: 
#     - ./**
#   include:
#     - ./src/**/*  

# layers:
#   samplelib:
#     path: src/layer/nodejs/node_modules # required, path to layer contents on disk
#     description: Description of what the lambda layer does # optional, Description to publish to AWS
#     licenseInfo: GPLv3 # optional, a string specifying license information
#     retain: false # optional, false by default. If true, layer versions are not deleted as new ones are created
#     # compatibleRuntimes:
#     #   - nodejs16.x
#     package:
#       patterns:
#         - "!**"
#         - src/**
    
    

functions:
  getSampleMessage:
    handler: src/lambda/sample/index.getSampleMessage
    # layers:
    #   - !Ref SamplelibLambdaLayer

  createSampleMessage:
    handler: src/lambda/sample/index.createSampleMessage
    

  getSampleJsonMessageJava:
    handler: com.serverless.Handler
    runtime: java11
    snapStart: true #https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/snapstart.html
    package:
      artifact: build/libs/app-rewards-todo-all.jar #${file(build/build.json):distribution}

appSync:
  name: app-rewards-api-${self:provider.stage}
  schema: schema.api.graphql
  authentication:
    type: 'API_KEY'
  apiKeys:
    - apiKey
  
  resolvers:
    Query.getSampleMessage:
      kind: UNIT
      dataSource: getSampleMessage
      request: mapping-templates/sample/Query.getSampleMessage.request.vtl
      response: mapping-templates/sample/Query.getSampleMessage.response.vtl
    Query.getSampleJsonMessageJava:
      kind: UNIT
      dataSource: getSampleJsonMessageJava
      request: mapping-templates/sample/Query.getSampleJsonMessageJava.request.vtl
      response: mapping-templates/sample/Query.getSampleJsonMessageJava.response.vtl  
    Mutation.createSampleMessage:
      kind: UNIT
      dataSource: createSampleMessage
      request: mapping-templates/sample/Mutation.createSampleMessage.request.vtl
      response: mapping-templates/sample/Mutation.createSampleMessage.response.vtl  


  dataSources:
    getSampleMessage:
      type: AWS_LAMBDA
      config:
        functionName: getSampleMessage
    getSampleJsonMessageJava:   
      type: AWS_LAMBDA
      config:
        functionName: getSampleJsonMessageJava 
    createSampleMessage:
      type: AWS_LAMBDA
      config:
        functionName: createSampleMessage
```

and here is my github build spec:

```
name: Deploy app Rewards

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  Dev-Deployment:
    name: dev deployment
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: dev
    #url : https://todo.com
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.17.0]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'temurin'
    - name: Build with Gradle
      uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@bd5760595778326ba7f1441bcf7e88b49de61a25 # v2.6.0
      with:
        arguments: build
    
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}    
    - run: npm ci #similar to npm install
    - run: node --version
    - name: Install Plugin and Deploy
      uses: serverless/github-action@v3.2
      with: # need this custom piece for the roles per function plugin https://github.com/marketplace/actions/serverless#usage-with-serverless-plugins
        args: -c "serverless plugin install --name serverless-iam-roles-per-function && serverless deploy --stage dev" 
        entrypoint: /bin/sh
      env:
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
```